# Why editing a post removes it from the review queue?

Tags: support

[This](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/17047) is just the latest example, but I have seen it happening other times:

1. a question is in the close queue
2. a reviewer edits the post from the queue
3. the question is removed from the queue by the system

Why is that? Is the system written to assume that any edit will automatically save the question, and that no more revision is necessary?

**NOTE:**
I am interested in the general case, NOT in the specific case linked. The linked case serves only as a reference to illustrate the current question.

---

**Edit with additional example:**

**Note to the edit:** This is only an example that shows a case of what I think is a problematic aspect of the behaviour described above, it does not want to discuss the edit, the user doing the edit or the post being edited.

The revision #4 for [this post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/30256/revisions) was done to clean up, but did not substantially change the content of the question.
The edit, though, was done from the review queue, and thus the post has been [removed from it](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/17100).

I think that the post needed more voices to chime in, but given the way the system is designed:

- someone (else from the previous time) has to flag the post again
- people that though it was not a good post will not be able to review it again, while people that voted to leave it open will able to cast their vote again

Comment: Is it fixed now?