# Can a post go in the "low quality" queue twice?

Tags: support, bug

I recently flagged [this post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/35422/1467). Given [the quirks](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/1467) of the SE review system, it was removed from the review queue after being edited.

DeltaLima says he re-flagged the post, but the post is not in the review queue. Does the system prevent a post from being reviewed twice? How does the review system work?

Comment: Good question. I added another flag to that answer, but it's still showing 0 posts in the LQP queue. It does seem that such posts are hanging around longer now that less of us have delete vote privileges after the graduation. Most of the regulars had it in beta, but there's only about a dozen now.

Comment: @reirab remember that in the queue you cannot see post you flagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since I've since found out the answer, to avoid others from stumbling on the same issue, the following [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295278/295232) gives the answer:

> If the post has already had a Low Quality review task, further flags will only appear in the moderator flag queue **unless the post has been edited since the last task was completed (or invalidated)**.

So the posts could go twice in the queue.

It is rare, but there have been cases of this happening.